# I'm trying to get an expanding grid with html and CSS but they just wont fit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get an expandable button to fit into a grid using HTML and CSS but they will not fit properly. I am still fairly new to HTML and CSS so I'm not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. I have a button style I like but I can not for the life of me get them to fit neatly into a grid.

[tying to get rid of the spaces between the buttons][1]

```
    <style>
    .grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template: auto / auto auto auto auto;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .collapsible {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        gap: 15px
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 18px;
        Border-radius: 15px;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
    }

    .active, .collapsible:hover {
        background-color: #555;
    }

    .collapsible:after {
        content: '\002B';
        font-weight: bold;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .active:after {
        content: "\2212";
    }

    .content {
        padding: 0 18px;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border-radius: 15px;    
    }
    </style> 

    <div class= "grid-container">
    <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p> Test </p>
        </div>
    <button class="collapsible">Open Collapsible</button>
        <div class="content">
            <p> Test </p>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;

   for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
       coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
       this.classList.toggle("active");
       var content = this.nextElementSibling;
       if (content.style.maxHeight){
           content.style.maxHeight = null;
       } else {
           content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
           } 
       });
    }
    </script>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/djtYl.png
```

Comment: What do you mean will not fit properly into the grid? can you explain further?

Comment: I cannot seem to get the spaces between the buttons to go away

Comment: ahh so you want to make button next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spaces occurs because the element content still taking up the space thou its not visible. if you want to remove the spaces between buttons, display the content element first to none then if active class is toggled then add some style to it to display the content. Here's the example.

```
.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 15px;    
    display: none; <-- new added
}
.active + .content { <-- new added
  display: block;
}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: I thank you for the help if it's not too much trouble do you know a way to get the content to appear below the button and not next to it

Comment: Yea, to make the content below, just wrap the button and the content element to another parent element. Just do another styling to adjust the layout. The idea is make the button and content relative and block to each other.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what I need to do. I make a new styling with the button and content but how do I get them to block each other? I'm sorry for the probably stuped question.